# ¿Se puede sobreescribir System.out.println("");?

Tags: java

Estoy en un proyecto escrito en Java algo avanzado donde he utilizado mucho los mensajes por consola. No me gustaria quitarlos, pero tampoco que se impriman si no lo defino yo así en alguna opción de configuración del programa(Por ejemplo correrlo en modo depuración).

Lo que quiero es dirigirlos a mi propia "consola de mensajes" donde pueda manipular esta información(Mostrar en pantalla, crear logs, etc). Actualmente tengo una función que simula la estructura (Una clase que llama a la consola y he nombrado la instancia y una función como `SystemOut.println()`) pero me gustaria sobreescribir `System.out.println("")` para no modificar el código que ya tengo definido y también capturar de manera inmediata las excepciones. ¿Es esto posible? Estoy abierto a recomendaciones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es posible cambiar el PrintStream que usa la clase System para escribir los mensajes. Ver en la documentación [System.setPrintStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-)

**Ejemplo**

```
PrintStream myStream = new PrintStream(System.out) {
    @Override
    public void println(String x) {
        super.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": " + x);
    }
};
System.setOut(myStream);
System.out.println("Hola mundo!");
```

**Salida:**

```
1420553422337: Hola mundo!
```

**Redirigir a un archivo**

Puede crear el PrintStream para escribir directamente en un archivo:

```
File file = new File("C:\\a.txt");
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file);
System.setOut(ps);
System.out.println("To File");
```

Y por último, la recomendación es usar un logger desde el comienzo del desarrollo, con eso se tiene control con la forma de loggear (Cambiar destino, nivel de detalle, formato del mensaje etc) sin cambiar el código.

Comment: Funciono perfectamente pero ¿Será posible sobrecargar `println()` de manera que pueda pasarle multiples parametros?